# DropDownList not setting selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm running asp.net 4 mvc and I've created a DropDownList of dates that defaults to the first entry in the list. When I select an entry, I invoke a controller function and do some processing. However, when my page does the PostBack, instead of displaying the list item I selected, it displays the original default list item again.

How do I get my page to display the last item I selected from the list? I've spent two full days searching this site and the Internet for a solution but nothing I try seems to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**My Html View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectList", Model.ReverseMonthsLists(),
    new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value)" })
<script>
    function CallChangefunc(val) {
        window.location.href = "/dashboard/Report_Performance?id=" + val;
    }
</script>
```

**My ViewModel**

```
public SelectList MonthList { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ReverseMonthsLists()
{
    var selectListItems = GetDates()
        .Select(_ => _.ToString("MMM yyyy"))
        .Select((dateString, index) => new SelectListItem { Selected = index == 0, Text = dateString, Value = dateString })
        .ToList();
    return selectListItems;
}


public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates()
{
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1).Date;
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    int numberOfMonthsToShow = (currentDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12 + currentDate.Month - startDate.Month;
    var dates = new List<DateTime>(numberOfMonthsToShow);
    currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonthsToShow; i++)
    {
        dates.Add(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);
    }

    return dates;
}
```

**My Controller**

```
[RequireLogin]
public ActionResult Report_Performance(string id)
{
    DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);
    if (id != null)
        newDate = DateTime.Parse(id);
    var aVar = Models.Reporting.ListingStatsReportingViewModel.GetStats(userCurrentService.CompanyId.Value, Models.Reporting.DateTimePeriod.Monthly, newDate);
    return this.View(aVar);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for the `GetStats` method? I'm guessing that it's always returning the same data, so it would help to see what's going on under the hood there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
window.location.href = "/dashboard/Report_Performance?id=" + val;
```

This essential tells the browser to navigate to a new page, which is an HttpGet operation.  Thus, there is no correlation between your current settings and those of a new page.

It's as if you had just gone up to the address bar and hit enter.  It issues a new page with all new defaults.

There are many ways you can address this problem.  The easiest would be to have some javascript that looks at the URL and extracts the id query parameter, then selects the item in the dropdown box that corresponds with the id.

Another option is to set the dropdownlist's selected value based on the ID in your controller.

In controller:

```
ViewBag.SelectedItem = id;
```

In View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", Model.ReverseMonthsLists(), ...)
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I'm so new at .Net and javascript that I don't quite understand how to do it. Can you please post a code example of how I would implement your solution?

Comment: @csharpMind - The code you posted doesn't really match, so i'm just going by what you posted.  For instance, your passing the result of the GetStats() method to your View as a model, and you haven't shown what that is.  It looks, based on the fact you're calling a method off the Model as if you're returning a reference to the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The GetStats() method is returning the requested stats as expected. I'm passing it a string value. The DropDownList automaticall defaults to the first entry in the list. In this,  case, "Jul 2017". But if I use the dropdown menu to select "Jun 2017", the Report_Performance controller functions is called and it executes the GetStats() method. The results are returned to the view, but my dropdown menu displays "Jul 2017" instead of "Jun 2017". I want the combo box to display "Jun 2017" which is what I selected.

Comment: Wow. What a simple solution. I re-read your post and made the changes you suggested and it worked like a champ! I think I was making this much harder than it needed to be. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code as follows:

Let's say your model class that is being returned by `GetStats` method in the `Report_Performance` action is `MyStats` which contains a string property named `SelectedDateString` (you need to add this property to your view model class).

Updated view markup:

```
@model MyStats
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDateString", Model.ReverseMonthsLists(),
    new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value)" })
<script>
    function CallChangefunc(val) {
        window.location.href = "/dashboard/Report_Performance?id=" + val;
    }
</script>
```

Updated controller:

```
[RequireLogin]
public ActionResult Report_Performance(string id)
{
    DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);
    if (id != null)
        newDate = DateTime.Parse(id);
    var aVar = Models.Reporting.ListingStatsReportingViewModel.GetStats(userCurrentService.CompanyId.Value, Models.Reporting.DateTimePeriod.Monthly, newDate);

    //This will make sure that the model returns the correct value of the property as a string.
    aVar.SelectedDateString = id;

    return this.View(aVar);
}
```

A `Html.DropDownList()` works by getting data from a `string property` in the model which is of the same name as the name of the DropDownList itself.

In your case, you need to set the DropDownList value using javascript or jquery as it's not connected to a model property.

Let me give you an example:
A drop down list in MVC can be created by using either

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PreferredContactMethod, Model.PreferredContactMethods, "")
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("PreferredContactMethod", Model.PreferredContactMethods, "")
```

In both cases, `PreferredContactMethod` is a string property in my model that is connected to the view - which is done by specifying `@model PreferredContactModel` at the top of the view.

In your case, your list name is selectList and if the specified model is connected to the view and if there's a property in the model that gets the selected date, then you need to change the name of your drop down list to it.

I hope it makes sense, if there's any issue, please comment back. I want to help with this.

Comment: All of the code involved in this process is posted above. When you say "if the specified model is connected to the view and if there's a property in the model that gets the selected date" I don't know what you mean. My model connection is "public SelectList MonthList { get; set; }" as shown above. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you put a `@model` statement in your view? And, does the return statement of `return this.View(aVar)` bring you back to the same view?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The return statement takes me back to the same view, with the first item in the list showing as if I were coming to the view for the very first time, instead of showing the list item I selected to get to the controller. The sum total of the code on the view is shown above.

Comment: The `@model <C# class name>` binds your view to the specified c# object (Model/ViewModel). When you return a view using `return View()` statement, you're essentially redirecting to the view and when you pass the object for example `aVar` in your case, you're redirecting to the view with that object as the model data which is automatically used to populate fields as specified by you.

Comment: You can either change the code as per suggestion by @Erik or you can add a `@model` statement at the top of the view followed by your view model class name which should be the same type as the `aVar` being returned by the `Report_Performance` action.

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Yatin - you basically just copied exactly what I wrote in my post.

Comment: I made the changes @Erik suggested before I saw your updated post and his solution worked perfectly. But thank you for your interest and attempts to help me find a solution.

Comment: I'm glad your issue is resolved. Enjoy learning .net, it's fun.

Comment: Sorry @Erik, the word is 'similar' not 'exactly' ;) - I favour models and I don't like using ViewBag.